# New Garage floor paint

Tags: paint, floor, garage

I am having a home built. I would like to paint the garage floor with Behr Granite Grip. Since it is a new home can I just sand and paint it? Thank you.

Comment: You should do some checking with the manufacturers and also read the directions on  Granite Grip.

Comment: This is more of a product question and therefore is going to get flagged and deleted.

Answer (score 2):

From the provided [product manual](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/2e/2e714fb9-f916-4ce6-896f-a38b523dd13a.pdf):

> (**Proper surface preparation is required**.) All surfaces must be clean,
> sound, dry and free of any dirt, oil, and grease. **Uncoated Concrete or
> Masonry Surfaces**: Allow new surfaces to cure 30 days. Clean and etch
> surface using a product such as a muriatic acid etcher (read and follow all
> manufacturer’s label directions) to achieve a textured profile similar to 150
> grit sandpaper. **Previously Coated Surfaces**: For a painted surface in sound
> condition, use a product to clean and prepare the surface. If the coating is
> failing or peeling, use a paint stripper to remove old coating or scrape/sand
> down to a sound concrete surface. Scuff sand glossy surfaces. Clean and spot
> etch any exposed concrete. Remove all dust with a damp cloth, allow to dry.

Comment: I always acid etch when painting concrete. I usually use epoxy paint specifically made for garage floors , some cheap brands peel up because the heat from tires.